# Reschedule queries after upgrading from Bulk API V1 to Bulk API V2

Tags: apex, bulk-api, bulk-api-v2

I checked the `Bulk Data Load Jobs` page and there are queries running in `Bulk V1` and currently org does not have `Bulk V2`. So, if Bulk Version is upgraded to V2, will these queries automatically run in `Bulk V2`. If not, what are the steps I need to take to reschedule these queries in `Bulk V2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jobs would need to be deleted and queued in Bulk API v2. Both v1 and v2 can run in an org at once, so there's no need to upgrade unless you want to take advantage of the new improved limits/features of v2. Note that this may involve updating the clients and/or configuring them to use v2. You can't fix this in Salesforce, it must be fixed by the client(s) that are in use.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox for answer. Yes, The reason to upgrade is to take advantage of Bulk V2 features. So basically what I am looking to know is, would the client need anything from salesforce to upgrade the job to V2. Is there any new endpoints/URL etc. that I would have to provide?

Comment: @devforce It's got more changes than just an endpoint change, but most of them are trivial. Have you looked at the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/)? It explains all the endpoints, etc you need.